# Is it correct and natural to say "what's the combined length of something" when you want to know the total length of something?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Would you tell if it is correct and natural to say *what's the combinened length of something* when you want to know the total length of something? For example:

> You said that one pallet measures 4 feet in length. Could you tell me what is the **combined length** of all the pallets?

If that's not natural, would you tell me what you would say?

Comment: I'm leaving this question open because it's about something specific, not just asking for proofreading or rephrasing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That can work but it would be more natural to use the other word you mentioned: **total**.

> You said that one pallet measures 4 feet in length. Could you tell me the **total length** of all the pallets?